# NextAuth Session doesn't set me access_token

Tags: next.js, next-auth

If I try to give the user an access_token, it doesn't work. All I get back in the session callback function are: name, email, image.
But I need additional information, including the access_token

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),

providers:[
    GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!!,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!!,
       
      })
],
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {   
     if(account)
      {
     token.accessToken = account?.access_token 
      }      
     return token
    }, 
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      //Gives me undefined
      console.log(token)
      if (token) {
      //No access_token from jwt
      session.user = token       
      }   

      console.log(session)
      return session
     
  },
  }
}
```

The result when I output the session in the client:

```
{
 user: {
 name: 'Max Mustermann',
 email: 'm.mustermann@test.com',
 image: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/cweawwqad...=s96-c'       
},
 expires: '2023-06-11T14:23:17.361Z'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Next Auth actually does assign an access token but it did not return it back with the session callback for security reasons but you can protect routes without try it out and it will works

how to protect or get the session back in client :

```
//Session
import { useSession, signOut } from "next-auth/react"

const {data:session} = useSession()

    {!section?.user && (
    <div>
        <button>Login</button> 
    </div>
    )}
```

how to protect or get the session back in api routes:

```
//auth 
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
//the authOptions path 
import { authOptions } from '../api/auth/[...nextauth]'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
const { method } = req;

const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)

if(!session){
  return  res.status(401).send({ message: 'Not Authenticated!' }); 
}
```

}

how to protect or get the session back in getServerSideProps:

```
//auth
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
//the authOptions path form api/auth/[...nextauth].js
import { authOptions } from '../../pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions)


if (!session) {
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: '/login',
      permanent: false,
    },
  }
}

const userData = session

return {
    props: {userData}
}

}
```

now if you wish to add something to the session callback you can do this in the  [...nextauth].js file :

```
export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    // OAuth authentication providers...
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code"
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  callbacks:{
    //i use the sign in call back here to store the register user in my database
    signIn: async ({ user, account }) => {
      await dbConnect()

      if (account.provider === "google") {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: user.email });

        if (existingUser) {
          user.userData = existingUser 
          return existingUser;
        }
        
        const randomPassword = crypto.randomBytes(8).toString('hex');

        const hashedPassword = await hash(randomPassword, 12);

        const newUser = await User.create({
          name: user.name,
          email:user.email,
          password:hashedPassword,
          provider:true,
          providerName:"google",
          verified:true
        });

        //this will take the new user and put in the user object into userData
        user.userData = newUser 

        return newUser;
      }
    },
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) =>{

      if (user) {
        token.uid = user;
      }

      return token
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {

        //here i created new object inside the session that hold the data that i want 
        session.userData = {
          isAdmin: token.uid.userData.isAdmin,
          id: token.uid.userData._id,
          image:token.uid.userData.image,
          provider:token.uid.userData.provider
        }

      //you have to return the session
      return session;
    },
  },
  strategy: "jwt",
  secret: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET,
  database: process.env.DB_URL  
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Comment: But as i said, it was working today with the same code i posted. Just since 2 hours it dosen't. Wondering why suddenly dosen't

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer for me, right from nextauth doc:

> When using database sessions, the User (user) object is passed as an argument.

> When using JSON Web Tokens for sessions, the JWT payload (token) is provided instead.

And since I'm using MongoDB as an adapter, I don't get an access_token back

Comment: what you need the access_token token for i told you before next auth does not include the token in the session callback but you still can perform securing app just fine